# How to add pinch zoom in/out to Android Studio ImageView?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, imageview, zooming, pinchzoom

For a while now, I have been struggling with adding zoom in/out to my images in Android Studio Kotlin project. I have tried numerous things from different sources and nothing worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions on which library to use, or an example of zoom in working code, recently used?

Thanks in advance.